# Call function with argument in event

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I have an `input`, and attached a `change` event to it. In that change event I called a function. Here's the code:

```
textInput.change(myFunction);
```

That works fine. But I want to pass a parameter to it. `myFunction('arg')` When I do that, the function calls itself right away, and not when there's a change event.

How can I call a function to the `change` event with arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's `onchange`.

Either bind the function:

```
textInput.onchange = myFunction.bind(this, 'a');
```

Or, if you don't want to explicitly use `bind`, just put the call to the function in the function `onchange` calls:

```
textInput.onchange = function () {
  myFunction('a');
};
```

Comment: The only difference would be my own preference?

Answer (score 1):

```
textInput.change(myFunction.bind(textInput, 'arg'));

function myFunction(arg1, event) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just pass an anonymous function like this:

```
textInput.change(function(){
  myFunction('arg');
});
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvote so that I may learn how to answer questions better in the future.