# Create new Function and pass parameters without calling it

Tags: javascript

In project there are implemented methods, that will execute the stack of functions asynchronously, but the problem is, they accept only the function, here is an example:

```
self.executeFunction = function(functionStackItem) {
// Some additional check and logics
// Some logging
    functionProcessor.processFunction({
        processableItem : functionStackItem
    });
};
```

So, we have such method, for creating functions that will be executed synchronously:

```
userFunction = new Function('globalVariable, logger', userCode);
userFunction(globalVariable, logger);
```

But now, as we move to the async i have to use the executeFunction method provided by the controller, the problem is, i don't know, how i can add those parameters in this code:

```
userFunction = new Function('globalVariable, logger', userCode);
// userFunction(globalVariable, logger); cannot use this, because this will call and execute function immediately
projectName.processingController.executeFunction(userFunction); // passing function, that will be executed as needed, but it doesn't contain parameters
```

**So as you can see in code above, the function gets passed, but the params that are needed: globalVariable and logger will be undefined - how can i fix it? Is there a way that doesn't require reworking the processingController?**

Comment: Could it be that you are you looking for `Function.apply()`?

Comment: Would `arguments` not solve your problem?

Comment: Maybe you have to use closure

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143802/call-function-with-argument-in-event, or too much of a stretch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either use a wrapper function:

```
projectName.processingController.executeFunction(function() {
    return userFunction(globalVariable, logger);
});
```

or if `this` is set by `executeFunction` to something meaningful:

```
projectName.processingController.executeFunction(function() {
    return userFunction.call(this, globalVariable, logger);
});
```

or [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
projectName.processingController.executeFunction(
    userFunction.bind(null, globalVariable, logger)
);
```

...but not if `executeFunction` sets `this` to something meaningful, since `bind` sets a specific `this` (I'm using `null` for that argument above).